# Compilation error at input\output files

Tags: c++, c, opencv

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void WriteInDB()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("result.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(filelist[i],"")!=0)
            myfile << filelist[i]<<"\n";
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

When I compile this program, I get the following errors:

> Error  14  error C2228: left of '.open' must have class/struct/union
>   Error  17  error C2228: left of '.close' must have class/struct/union
>   Error  11  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'myfile'
>   Error  10  error C2065: 'ofstream' : undeclared identifier
>   Error  12  error C2065: 'myfile' : undeclared identifier
>   Error  13  error C2065: 'myfile' : undeclared identifier
>   Error  15  error C2065: 'myfile' : undeclared identifier
>   Error  16  error C2065: 'myfile' : undeclared identifier

Can anybody help me to resolve them?

Answer (score 3):

ostream is a part of the std namespace. As such you need to add:

```
using namespace std;
```

Alternatively you can prefix all instances of ostream with std::, ie:

`std::ofstream myfile`.

Comment: `using namespace` is considered deprecated. The alternative is to put `using std::ofstream` in the function.

Comment: @larsmans: I have not seen anything saying its deprecated. I personally think its very bad practice (but a lot of people still do it).

Comment: I'm referring to C++ guru Herb Sutter's "Namespace Rule #1: Avoid `using` directives entirely". It's not deprecated in the standard of course, maybe I used the wrong term. Perhaps Sutter's "marauding army of crazed barbarians that sows indiscriminate destruction wherever it passes" is better :)

Comment: I agree, in general I avoid the 'using namespace' as it can potentially lead to conflicts. However, its not always easy to explain, specially for someone who is being introduced to namespaces for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to prepend all the standard library stuff with `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int const filelist_length = 512;
char *filelist[filelist_length];
// you actually seem to use empty strings rather than null pointers as emtpy
// entries; consider a vector<string> instead

void WriteInDB() {
  using namespace std;
  ofstream myfile ("result.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < filelist_length; i++) {
    if (strcmp(filelist[i], "") != 0) {
      myfile << filelist[i] << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```